# Playwright multiple downloads

Tags: typescript, playwright

I am writing a playwright script to download files from the browser. The current piece of code only downloads one file. But there are multiple files.

```
const download = await Promise.all([
            page.waitForEvent("download"),
            page.locator("td[data-action='Master File']").click({ force: true })
        ])
        const fileName = download[0].suggestedFilename()
        await download[0].saveAs(fileName)
```

How to download multiple files

Comment: The page.locator appears to be clicking a <td> element which likely downloads one thing. Or does it prompt for a user to select multiple files?

Comment: What is the length of the download array? Does download[1] contain your next file?

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk
the element does download 2 files. but from this code only saves one

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are only seeing the one being saved because you are specifically only accessing the first value in the array of values, when you say `[0]`, you need to iterate over each value and save each.

```
let downloadArray = await Promise.all([
            page.waitForEvent("download"),
            page.locator("td[data-action='Master File']").click({ force: true })
        ])

downloadArray.forEach((downloadItem, indexPosition) => {

    let fileName = downloadArray[indexPosition].suggestedFilename()
    downloadItem.saveAs(fileName)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for multiple/bulk downloads:

```
const bulkDownload(page: Page): Promise<Download[]> {
  const downloads: Download[] = [];
  page.on( 'download', ( download: Download ) => {
    downloads.push( download );
  } );

  // Perform action which triggers downloads, for example:
  await page.locator('button.button-download').click();

  // Wait for 'download' events to propagate
  // Note: This duration is arbitrarily defined - could be shorted
  await page.waitForTimeout(200);

  return downloads;
}

const downloads: Download[] = await bulkDownload();
const downloadedFileNames = downloads.map( download => download.suggestedFilename() );
```